# Арифметика с плавающей точкой

Tags: linux, bash

Возникла необходимость перевести секунды в милисекунды.
Скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ffprobe -i c848a39afc54e04cc64ddd955686654b9b1c6f31 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0");
b=1000;
result=$(($a*$b));
echo $result
```

Вывод

> ./sectomilisec: line 4: 23.760000*1000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".760000*1000")

Как правильно умножить вывод операции на число?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".760000*1000")

в программе *bash* не реализована арифметика с плавающей точкой (только целочисленная).

для осуществления таких вычислений придётся воспользоваться какой-то другой программой. например, *bc*:

```
result=$(echo "$a*$b" | bc -l)
```

или *dc*:

```
result=$(echo "$a $b + p" | dc)
```

---

подробности:

- *bc*: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc), [`man bc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc), [`info bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)
- *dc*: [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc), [`man dc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc), [`info dc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html).

---

кстати, в этом выражении знаки доллара перед именами переменных не нужны:

```
result=$(($a*$b))
```

достаточно (и более правильно) так:

```
result=$((a*b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильная операция умножения выполняется вот так

```
echo $[$a*$b]
echo $[5*10]
```

Если нужно умножать целое на вещественное то требуется выполнить команду

```
result=$(echo "scale=4; $a*$b" | bc)
```

scale - точность

Comment: всё-таки следует использовать `$((a*b))`. ведь: *The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.*

Comment: При коде <pre>#!/bin/bash
a=$(ffprobe -i c848a39afc54e04cc64ddd955686654b9b1c6f31 -show_entries format=du$
echo $(($a*1000))<pre> вывод ./sectomilisec: line 3: 23.760000*1000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".760000*1000") что тоже не верно.

Comment: Как я понимаю не нравится точка в числе?